# Как использовать методы в генераторах списков?

Tags: python

Например:

```
a = [{1:'1'},{2:'2'},{3:'3'}]
for i in a:
    i.setdefault('add', 5)
```

Как записать это генератором?
Что-то типа такого нужно:

```
a = [{1:'1'},{2:'2'},{3:'3'}]
b = [i.setdefault('add', 5) for i in a]
# Результат нужен такой как выше, не три 5 в списке
# Заодно подвопрос, откуда там три 5 берется если я вроде вставляю словарь?
```

В общем как методы в них использовать и можно ли вообще?

Comment: Правило большого пальца: никогда не использовать методы с побочными эффектами внутри выражений.

Comment: "три 5 в списке" объясняется тут: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не совсем понял вопрос

вам нужен вот такой вариант?

```
a = [{1:'1'}, {2:'2'}, {3:'3'}]
b = [i | {'add': 5} for i in a]
```

вывод будет аналогичен тому, что вы привели в самом начале поста

Comment: Оно, а что тут вертикальная линия означает?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#specification

Comment: @Random.random, объединение словарей

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{1:'1'},{2:'2'},{3:'3'}]
for i in a:
    i.setdefault('add', 5)
```

здесь у тебя ключи 1 и 2 удаляются, затем создаётся новый словарь из последнего элемента списка и добавляется к новому словорю значение по умолчанию
то есть если в цикле вывести i то получишь

```
5
{1: '1', 'add': 5}
5
{2: '2', 'add': 5}
5
{3: '3', 'add': 5}
```

Comment: Ключи 1 и 2 не удаляются.

Comment: Не думаю что это так работает)

Answer (score 0):

как получить обновленный список тут уже подсказали, а вот как можно "впихнуть" метод в генератор:

```
a = [{1:'1'}, {2:'2'}, {3:'3'}]
b = [i.setdefault('add', 5) and i for i in a]
print(b)
```

результат:

```
[{1: '1', 'add': 5}, {2: '2', 'add': 5}, {3: '3', 'add': 5}]
```